# How to remove <br> and special characters like &#�?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to develop the dynamic site using php and mysql. I need to extract limited contents from my database so I've used **substr** but I'm troubled with unnecessary enter so want to remove enter (br) and special characters like &#�?.

My code looks like this.

```
 <?php
 $sql = "SELECT contents FROM table";
 $result = mysql_query($sql)  or die(mysql_error());
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
 $contents = $row['contents'];
 echo substr($fld_page_details, 0,125); 
 }
 ?>
```

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: So you want to remove `<br>` and `&#�` only? Or do you want to remove other special characters?

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. It's awful and is being removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices. Always be absolutely **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will have severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: –  Dave ChenI want to remove other special characters also.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set like this to set character set `mysql_set_charset("UTF8");` and `header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`

```
<?php

  $sql = "SELECT contents FROM table";
  mysql_set_charset("UTF8");
  $result = mysql_query($sql)  or die(mysql_error());
  header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
   $contents = $row['contents'];
   echo substr($fld_page_details, 0,125); 
  }
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove html tags you can use strip_tags().

```
$htm = "<b>Hello world</b>";
$rsp = strip_tags($html);
var_dump($rsp);
```

[More info](http://php.net/manual/es/function.strip-tags.php)

Comment: No I need to use substr to extract certain content. I just want to remove br (enter) only.